# W3 total Cache WordPress Plugin still query database after enabled

Tags: wordpress, caching, w3-total-cache

Does anyone know the setting or how to stop W3 Total Cache plugins to not query the database when the page is requested?

I put this plugin on the test site,

- Enabled Page caching
- Enabled Database Caching
- Enabled object Caching
- Enabled minify for css, js etc

However, it is still querying the database for both file basic or memcached caching method.

Does anyone know the settings required so page requests doesn't query the database?

Comment: Do you try in incognito? It's possible that when you are logged in (or still have some logged-in cookies), the cache is bypassed.

Comment: Hi Mtxz, I have it logged in on a normal chrome and use incognito tabs to tests.  For the incognito, I have inspection on and use CTRL + click the Reload/refresh button on the left of the URL of the chrome window/tab.  I see the DB get hit every time I refresh the page this way.

Comment: How do you check that your database is queried? Query monitor plugin? Live MySQL server command output? There is no difference between the number of query with W3 enable VS disabled?

Comment: Did you fix your issue?

Comment: @Mtxz, Sorry for the delay in response.  I do a MySQL query for processlist every second.  On normal return, there is one query but when I hit the site to test it (on local development with only 1 WordPress testing site is on this MySQL server), I get 2 MySQL query.  The debugging Timestamp also change as well.

Comment: Hum. Can you check the number of query for the same page load with and without the cache plugin enabled, and being logged-out? To see if there is at least one change. Run each condition 2 or 3 times and compare all runs